# Heroku Postgres Error: Column does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I'm getting the following error after I deploy to heroku (running PG), though it works fine in local (running sqlite3)

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR:  column "calendar_day" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ated_at > '2012-04-09 19:39:54.787077') AND (date(calendar_d...
                                                         ^
SELECT  date(created_at) as calendar_day, count(*) as total_checkins FROM "checkins"  WHERE (user_id = 1 AND group_id = 1 AND created_at > '2012-04-09 19:39:54.787077') AND (date(calendar_day) = '2012-05-07') GROUP BY date(created_at) LIMIT 1):
...
app/helpers/groups_helper.rb:32:in `checkin_day'
```

Note that "calendar_day" is not an actual column on a persisted table, but one I define on the fly using an AS statement (not sure what this is technically called). The relevant helper functions are shown below. Basically, at the top of the page I make a call to calendar_view, later I pass the results to checkin_day as the checkins parameter. It's on this checkin_day call that I hit the error. Any idea why this works fine in local but not in heroku?

```
def calendar_view(member, timeperiod)
  Checkin.select("date(created_at) as calendar_day, count(*) as total_checkins").where("user_id = ? AND group_id = ? AND created_at > ?", member.member.id, member.group.id, Time.now - timeperiod.days).group("date(created_at)")
end

def checkin_day(checkins, day)
  ch = checkins.where("date(calendar_day) = ?", day).first
  return ch.total_checkins if ch
  return 0
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff you define on the SELECT part of the query (projection)  is not available during the evaluation of the WHERE clause (selection). You have to define it again there:

```
def checkin_day(checkins, day)
  ch = checkins.where("date(created_at) = ?", day).first
  return ch.total_checkins if ch
  return 0
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to define again without having to re-run the original query? When I look at the output of the original query on the console I see two columns, one named "calendar_day" and the other "total_checkins". I'm able to reference these columns in subsequent statements within the console. If I understand you correctly though, this won't work in PG?

Comment: What I described is the query handling inside of the PostgreSQL server. The behavior is the same in all relational database servers. The basic steps for query evaluation are: build the set (with joins...), selection (filtering rows, i.e. WHERE conditions), projection (choosing/renaming columns). This is done roughly in this order (save any optimizations). But generally, the projection definition is completely independent from the selection. And again, the handling of the result in ruby is completely independent from the query evaluation inside the database.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. Whether something works in the console is independent of how the database server will respond. I went ahead and changed the checkin_day method as you suggest and it works in PostgreSQL. Thanks for your help!